# Integrating SWT and JMF in Eclipse

Tags: java, swt, mp3, javasound, jmf

Trying to build a simple MP3 player with a GUI front end. Basically I can get an mp3 to play fine using JMF but when I import/use org.eclipse.swt it just refuses to play the mp3. I am guessing that somehow that using SWT is conflicting in some way with JMF but I dont know how or how to fix it.

Comment: Please don't use JMF, the last version came up in 2004.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to help you without any code/stacktrace/...

Comment: Joey, what would you recommend instead of JMF?

Comment: The `mp3plugin.jar` of the JMF is an MP3 SPI that adds support to Java Sound to read MP3s.  There is no need to add the entire JMF API to the class-path.